# How do I Reference Kivy widgets created from a Loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to somehow store a reference/string in MDFieldTexts (or MDButtons) created in a loop.

I am creating an internal blog for my app, all of the posts/widgets are generated using a loop. When a user enters a comment into the MDFieldText, I need to know which posts they are interacting with so that that kivy can update firebase accordingly.

I am wondering if there is a way to store a unique string in the MDFieldTexts or MDButtons as they are being generated.

The code below is an extract of the main project.

```
from functools import partial
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField


class UserInput(MDTextField):
    def print_input(self, *args):
        print(f"{self.text}")
        self.text = ""

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = MDGridLayout(cols=1, spacing=20)
        for i in range(5):
            input = UserInput()
            screen.add_widget(input)
            button = MDFlatButton(text=f"Submit #{i}", on_release=partial(input.print_input))
            screen.add_widget(button)

        return screen

MainApp().run()
```

Comment: there are many ways, simplest one would be `on_release=partial(f'id_{i}' ,input.print_input)` then recognize the button in your partial function with first argument.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code, do you need to do kind of a function that can get the text while typing on it? And at the same time do you need that text to be updated in the cloud? If that's what you are needing for your program I may have an answer